# Will Windows prompt the user for the 4 digit code to log in - when a user is logged in?

Tags: windows-10, passwords, login-screen

One of our users says they got a prompt that looked like a Windows system prompt asking them for their 4 digit login code. They were already logged in (obviously).

Can this happen? Or was this something bad running on their system that prompted for it? (They should have asked first, but at least they told me.)

And if this was not Windows, where do they go to change that code?

Comment: that's why Windows Server typically requires you to press Ctrl+Alt+Del by default before logging in to prevent any kind of fake login screen appearing

Comment: @phuclv Which now brings up another question, they have a phishing program running on their computer. How do I find and remove it?

Comment: I don't know. Probably you need some good antivirus and antimalware

Comment: @phuclv I ran Anti Malware and Trend Micro - nothing. And the machine seems to be running fine. So that has me thinking it was a valid prompt by Windows. It would be nice to know though if Windows does do this at times.